# How do I persist a route in Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, tcpip

I have a route that I am manually adding at each reboot:

```
route add -net 192.168.126.0/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

How can I make this route persistent?

I've seen quite a few articles online that suggest adding the following to /etc/networking/interfaces:

```
up route add -net 192.168.126.0/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

but when I try this, the machine comes up without this route appearing in the routing table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

putting it in /etc/networking/interfaces is often the best approach, you just have to put it in the right place... you didn't specify where you put it.

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  up $COMMAND_HERE
```

I'm in the habit of using "ip" instead of "route". Another example:

```
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.100
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.254
  up ip route add 192.168.126.0/24 via 192.168.1.253
```

Should work!

Comment: under debian the package iproute provides the ip binary

Answer (score 0):

```
route add -net 192.168.126.0/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

You can also add that to your /etc/rc.local